# "Windows Boot Manager" is the only "OS" that Ubuntu 15.10 Disc can find, therefore I'm missing the "Install alongside windows 7"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I've seen in most of the tutorials/guides to installing Ubuntu along windows 7 that Ubuntu finds Windows 7 automatically and makes installing easy. 
But Ubuntu is only finding "Windows Boot Manager" and won't give me the option. This has got to be an easy fix. Thanks!

This is the Ubuntu 15.10 Disc I'm referring to.

Comment: Where can't you find Windows 7? In the installer? In the GRUB menu? Have you tried installing alongside "Windows Boot Manager"? If you are not sure about what to do choose "Advanced option" in the installation and do the partitioning yourself (don't do it unless you know exactly what you're doing).

Comment: @EduardoCola Yes, I cannot find it in the Installer. There is no "alongside" boot manager, I don't remember what the option was. I think it was only to replace. I tried looking up how to do that but the hard drive is actually failing right now so I'm going to wait, thank you